# Add Create Account Box to Homepage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to add a "Create Account" box to the sidebar of my homepage. I added it to my application layout but I only want it to appear when the user is on my homepage. What is the best way to detect which page you are on and when to render the content?

```
 <% if current_page? %>

 <%= render layout/create_account %>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it via `content_for`

In your sidebar insert this:

```
<%= yield :create_account_box %>
```

And then in your homepage view do this:

```
<% content_for :create_account_box do %>
   render your box here.
<% end %>
```

This technique allows to inject content from subviews to superviews without any `if`s or stuff like that.